# Why can I not access my object property through dot notation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  creditCard: String,
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }]
});
```

I am attempting to access 'balanceDate' within 'balance'.

In my React front-end, I set state upon componentDidMount to 'debts', which is initiated as an empty array:

```
this.state = {
      debts: []
    }
```

I then filter down based upon whether a certain criteria is met:

```
const creditCards = this.state.debts.filter((x) => { return x.creditCard === 'true' })
```

From there, I then want to access each of the 'balanceDates'. I'm attempting to do this through map:

```
const databaseMonth = creditCards.map(x => x.balance.balanceDate)
```

However, it's returning undefined each time..... And I have no explanation as to why.

If I change it to:

```
const databaseMonth = creditCards.map(x => x.balance[x.balance.length - 1].balanceDate)
```

It successfully returns the last entry in the array, and its balance date, perfectly.

So why is my 'map' without the .length not working?

Can anyone tell me how I can access each of the balanceDates?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of "schema" is that, and are you sure it is accurate? Does it actually match the values you are receiving in the frontend? Please do `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.debts))` and post the result here

Comment: `balanceDate` is in an object inside an array. You'll need to specify the index of the object in `balance` to access its properties. `balance[0].balanceDate`

Comment: "*It successfully returns the last entry in the array,*" - as you say, `x.balance` is an array. `x.balance[index].balanceDate` does work, `x.balance.balanceDate` does not.

Comment: It's a Mongoose Schema. The schema is 100% accurate and functioning. Pilchard is right too, it's an object inside an array, but how do I access it>

Comment: "*How I can access each of the balanceDates*" - `creditCards.flatMap(x => x.balances).map(b => b.balanceDate)` should do

Comment: Flat map works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: creditCards.flatMap(x => x.balance.flatMap(s=>s.balanceDate)) should work